# How do I disable the vga16fb module during Ubuntu Server setup?

Tags: server, graphics

I have used the instructions given in the following link to fix the slow Hyper-V console of a Ubuntu Server box.

http://solyaris.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/ubuntu-10-04-on-intel-driver-and-server-frame-buffer/

I am hoping that there is a way to fix the problem before the install so that the installation routine won't take so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible suggestions you could try - during the install you should be given the option to edit your boot line.

Try adding `video=vga16fb:off` immediately before `quiet splash`.

Alternatively try the option `vga16fb.modeset=0`

Comment: awesome!!! the "vga16fb.modeset=0" option worked!!!

Comment: I now get the following error message on my new install
"gva16fb: Unknown parameter 'modeset'"

any suggestions?

Comment: once you've installed, you'll need to blacklist the vga16fb kernel module as per your linked article - you wont need to use vga16fb.modeset=0 in your grub boot option.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood in your link, all your did was blacklist the vga16fb module so it won't load at startup. You can dynamically unload a module from the command line using the rmmod command. So if you are using the GUI installed try opening a terminal and running the command:

```
sudo rmmod vga16fb
```

Comment: can this be done from the server install disk, before starting install, so that the installer itself will not be sluggish?